# Will Google Cloud Bigtable be HIPAA compliant?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

Will Google Cloud Bigtable be a HIPAA compliant data repository? In particular, will it support on disk encryption? And how much of the data will be stored concurrently with other users?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is really a legal question, not a programming one.

Comment: Google Cloud Bigtable is now HIPAA-compliant; see updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's address each of the questions in your post separately:

> Will Google Cloud Bigtable be a HIPAA compliant data repository?

Google Cloud Bigtable is now [HIPAA compliant](https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance#hipaa) (emphasis mine):

> ### HIPAA
>
> Google Cloud Platform will also support HIPAA covered customers by entering into a Business Associates Agreement. The Cloud Platform BAA currently covers [...long list of products...] and **Cloud Bigtable**.

---

> In particular will it support on disk encryption?

Google Cloud Platform already encrypts all data at rest, so this is an existing feature for all of our products, including Google Cloud Bigtable. For details, see our whitepaper [Encryption at rest](https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-at-rest/).

Google Cloud Bigtable stores data on a distributed file system called [Colossus](http://www.wired.com/2012/07/google-colossus/) (the successor to [Google File System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_File_System), aka GFS), which is referred to generically as "distributed file system" in this whitepaper.

> And how much of the data will be stored concurrently with other users?

This question is not clear: what do you mean by "concurrently"? Happy to discuss this with you further, please feel free to reach out to me (e.g., via LinkedIn) — I am the product manager for Cloud Bigtable.